# jQuery Horizontal image slider

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow, carousel

I need an images slideshow like this: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_51115/
But without scrolling feature on mouse position. Did you know a plugin to recommend me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)

Easy to use. Has a lot configuration parameters. I think it is quite good.

Comment: write a jQuery .click() function with a selector which points to thee class of the thumb maybe. I could be more specific because I don't know what do you want exactly.